# Where am I going wrong using promises and async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have written a function in 'apiCalls.js' file and have the following function:

```
function getAllData() {
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    async.parallel([
      function(callback) {
        request('http://urlcall', function(error, response, body) {
          if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return callback(null, body);
          }
          return callback(error || new Error('Response non-200'));
        });
      },
      function(callback) {
        request('http://urlcall', function(error, response, body) {
          if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return callback(null, body);
          }
          return callback(error || new Error('Response non-200'));
        });
      },
    ],
    function(err, results) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      }
      console.log(results);
      resolve(results);
    });
  });
}
```

I am then calling this function in my app.js file:

```
apiCalls.getAllData().then(function(returned) {
    console.log(returned);
    res.render('home');
  });
```

I am getting an error where the value returned in then is undefined:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I have resolved the promise and then used that value in the then function. Am I missing something here? I am new to using promises and asynchronous programming so am I missing some understanding here of how it is supposed to work?

Comment: For one thing, you're not returning the promise from your `getAllData()` function.  You might try `return new Promise ...`

Comment: You're going wrong by using promises and `async` together at all - the two styles just don't mix well. Use `request-promise` and `Promise.all` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you really don't want to mix promises with plain callbacks with the `async` library.  You need to pick one model to work with (promises or callbacks) and program all your control flow in one model.  So, if you're moving to promises (which most of the world is), then skip the async library entirely.  In this particular case, `Promise.all()` serves your purpose for two parallel requests.

Then, look to promisify the lowest level asynchronous operations you have as that lets you use promises for all your control flow and error handling.  In your case, that's the request library which already has a promisified version called request-promise.  In addition, it already checks for a non-2xx status for you automatically (and rejects the promise) so you don't have to code that.  So, it appears you could replace every you have with just this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');    // promise version of the request library

function getAllData() {
    return Promise.all([rp('http://urlcall1'), rp('http://urlcall2')]);
}
```

Then, you can use it with `.then()`:

```
apiCalls.getAllData().then(returned => {
    console.log(returned);
    res.render('home', returned);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the best explanation on promises I have gotten!